# H-bridge bypass when powered off

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

I have a need to insert a motor driver between a motor and an existing motor driver.  I need my circuit to become transparent or fail out of the way when powered off so that the existing motor driver continues to work.  Anyone know of a motor driver IC that remains in this state when powered off, or any other ideas on how to make this work?  Perhaps divert to my internal motor driver with a load switch when powered on?

Any thoughts on how to make this work much appreciated.  Merry Christmas!

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Besides, did you ever consider what it would be like for your motor driver to be trying to use the output of another motor driver for power? One that is constantly switched, interrupted. Not to mention the existing motor driver might even need phasing VI information to function properly and how it would get that  through your motor driver.

Comment: NO relays comes to mind.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it's an XY problem, I want my circuit in insert itself and drive this DC motor when needed, but if my circuit fails, I need to be able to power it off and retain the existing controls.  I could use a relay and flip the motor driver circuit to my own, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution that didn't require a mechanical component.

Comment: "*I want my circuit in insert itself and drive this DC motor when*" That's the XY problem part. Why would you ever need this? Swapping out DC motor drivers is one thing, but actually intercepting a motor driver with another driver is quite another and has all the problem I previously mentioned. It is unlikely to work if it is as your words say it is.